# Get Number of site visitors per week in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2019

I have a SharePoint site collection and I want to show the number of Visitors in a week on Home page. Anyone can please suggest me to do this task. I want to show the number of user visited to my site in the current week.

I will pass the parameter as a current week like Week 1 or week 2.

Expected Result: Week 1- Number of visitors to the site : 20.
                 Week 2- Number of visitors to the site : 40.

Please suggest if is there any REST API for it ?

SharePoint Version : SharePoint 2019.

Comment: You might be able to access visitor data through the search API. Do you get any interesting data if you navigate in your web browser to `{your site here}/_api/search/query?querytext='Path={your site here}'&selectproperties='Title,ViewsLast1DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast2DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast3DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast4DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast5DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast6DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsLast7DaysUniqueUsers,ViewsRecentUniqueUsers,ViewsLastMonths1Unique,ViewsLastMonths2Unique,ViewsLastMonths3Unique,ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers,Path'&orderBy=ViewsRecent&trimDuplicates=false&rowlimit=5000`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is any rest api to get visitors for site/sitecollection. But you can develop spfx extension, and each time somebody opens the page it can increment value based on some logic. Disadvantage is that the list with information must be accessible for all users to write. Something like telemetry ...